# Android Progress Bar not working for me

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

Progress bar is not working for me. I am try to show some details in Progress. But I can't, What I did wrongly? Please help me.

Activity Filename - MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sqliteexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ProgressDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,getString(R.string.loading) ,getString(R.string.alignMsg));
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading", "Loading the Image of the Day");
    Thread th = new Thread()
    {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(
                    new Runnable (){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }});
        }};
        th.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: In display, I can't see 'Loading the Image of the Day' string.

Comment: Also, remove the lines associated with `Thread th = new Thread() {`, it's completely pointless. you already made another thread by calling `handler.post()`.
BTW, does the application crash or post anything in the LogCat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using `handler.postDelayed` :

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
         "Loading", "Loading the Image of the Day");
handler.postDelayed(runnable,10000);
}
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      /* dismiss  dialog here*/
      dialog.dismiss();

      handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
   }
};
```

or you will need to move `Thread.sleep(10000);` inside Thread run method instead of inside Runnable which you are passing to `Handler.post` method as:

```
Thread th = new Thread()
    {
        public void run() {
            /** call Thread.Sleep here... **/
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            handler.post(
            ....your code here....
```

Comment: your second solution is useful and it is working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `handler` is defined in main activity and thus it will run on UI thread. You ask to sleep for 10 seconds and this won't work on the UI thread.

If you want to show the progress bar and dismiss it after 10 seconds then use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`.

This is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,getString(R.string.loading) ,getString(R.string.alignMsg));
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Loading the Image of the Day");
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Hope it was helpful.